# How to display events from "selectable" multiple calendars using FullCalendar React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a "simple" React App that allow a user to select/unselect calendars to display in a `@FullCalendar/React` component. The app loads a list of calendars from the server, and then the user may select or unselect calendars - and the FullCalender component should update accordingly.

Below is a simplified version on Codesandbox with simulated server fetches. You'll notice it loads correctly, but FullCalendar doesn't update as calendars are selected. In the console, you can see the data is being updated, but not re-rendered in the calendar display.

[image: Edit @FullCalendar/React Multiple Calendars]

The component that is causing the issues is `CalendarDisplay`. When render() is called again to update the display, the `events={this._fetchEvents}` handle is not called. Instead I'm wondering if I should use something like `events={this.state.events}` but then I run into the issue of knowing what date range FullCalendar is displaying.

```
/**
 * Display FullCalendar componenent with events from the selected calendars
 */
class CalendarDisplay extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      // not used
      events: []
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log("Rendering FullCalendar...");

    return (
      <FullCalendar
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
        events={this._fetchEvents}
      />
    );
  }

  _fetchEvents = (info, successCallback, failureCallback) => {
    // Loop through props.calendars to see which calendars to fetch events for
    this.props.calendars.forEach((calendar) => {
      // Fetch events for calendar if "shown" using date range from FullCalendar
      if (calendar.shown) {
        let events = fetchEventsFromServer(
          calendar.id,
          info.start.valueOf(),
          info.end.valueOf()
        );

        // Load into FullCalendar
        successCallback(events);
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the way to do this is to make use of the FullCalendar EventSource api and update the event sources after the component is mounted or updated.
A working example is at the CodeSandbox below and the relavent code is posted below as well.

[image: Edit @FullCalendar/React Multiple Calendars]

```
class CalendarDisplay extends Component {
  calendarRef = createRef();

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    this._fetchEvents();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._fetchEvents();
  }

  /**
   * The trick is to render the FulCalendar with no events
   * and use the EventSource api after the component mounts
   * or updates
   */
  render() {
    return (
      <FullCalendar
        ref={this.calendarRef}
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
        initialView="dayGridMonth"
      />
    );
  }

  /**
   * Method to add/remove EventSources when the components props
   * update (Calendars are selected/unslected)
   */
  _fetchEvents() {
    // Loop through props.calendars to see which calendars are selected
    this.props.calendars.forEach((calendar) => {
      let calendarApi = this.calendarRef.current.getApi();
      let eventSource = calendarApi.getEventSourceById(calendar.id);

      // Remove if present and unselected
      if (eventSource && !calendar.shown) {
        console.log("Removing EventSource. CalendarId: " + calendar.id);
        eventSource.remove();

        // Add if selected and not present
      } else if (calendar.shown && !eventSource) {
        calendarApi.addEventSource({
          id: calendar.id,
          events: function (info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
            // Here is where you would place your ajax() call
            let events = fetchEventsFromServer(
              calendar.id,
              info.start.valueOf(),
              info.end.valueOf()
            );
            // Load into FullCalendar
            successCallback(events);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```